# Can WSO2 MB handle HTTP requests?

Tags: wso2, jms, messagebroker, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I've been working with `WSO2 Message Broker` in order to publish and consume messages through `jms` and other clients. I've gone through the official [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/JMS+Client+Samples) including the samples.

What I want to know is that, is it possible for `WSO2 MB` to handle http requests directly instead of `jms`. Yes you can do something like [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/JMS+Synchronous+Invocations+%3A+Dual+Channel+HTTP-to-JMS), by converting http to jms through `WSO2 ESB` which seems like a long process.

ie: I mean having http as the end point or the transport to publish and consume messages directly in `WSO2 Message Broker`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you will have to use ESB + MB set up as explained at [1]. What you can do is to use ESB to wrap JMS functionality using a HTTP client. It is recommended to use ESB externally in a separate JVM when using this setup.

[1] http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/03/configuring-wso2-esb-wso2-message-broker/

Regards,
Pubudu.